# Make sure only one PyQt window is shown

Tags: python, qgis-plugins, pyqt5

I am developing a plugin for QGIS 3.10.
In part of my plugin, I have a UI using PyQt.

This form needs to be a singleton.
But when I have click several times on the plugin it generates several forms

Here is my code for UI

```
class AddDuctUI(QtWidgets.QDialog, FORM_CLASS):
    __instance = None
    def __new__(cls,*val):
        if AddDuctUI.__instance is None:
            AddDuctUI.__instance = QtWidgets.QDialog.__new__(cls)
        AddDuctUI.__instance.val = val
        return AddDuctUI.__instance
    
    
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Constructor."""
        super(AddDuctUI, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

When I check the object it is single instance but I have several windows shown.
This is the way I call the UI:

```
def show_form(self):
     main_dlg=AddDuctUI()
        self.main_dlg.show()
        result = self.main_dlg.exec_()
        
        if not result:
            self.reset()
            
        if result:
           self.apply_changes()
           self.reset()
```

How can I make sure only one window from this UI is shown at the time?